# I try to lay out a match for receiving a name from url but I receive a match undefinde

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I encountered such an error match undefind. I'm taking an old course on React did everything as shown in the lesson but I get an error why. i don't understand why match undefinde. Maybe you need to pick up the match in another way or somehow pass it ??

```js
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom'
import { NavBar } from "./components/NavBar";
import { Home } from './pages/Home'
import { About } from './pages/About'
import { Profile } from './pages/Profile'
import { Alert } from "./components/Alert";
import { AlertState } from "./context/alert/AlertState";
import { GithubState } from "./context/github/GithunState";

function App() {
  return (
    <GithubState>
      <AlertState>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <NavBar />
          <div className="container pt-4">
            <Alert alert={{text: 'Test Alert'}} />
            <Routes>
              <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
              <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
              <Route path="/profile/:name" element={<Profile />} />
            </Routes>
          </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </AlertState>
    </GithubState>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```js
import React from 'react'
import { useContext, useEffect } from 'react';
import { GithubContext } from '../context/github/githubContex';

export const Profile = ({match}) => {

    // const github = useContext(GithubContext)
    // const name = match.params.name

    // useEffect(() => {
    //     github.getUser()
    //     github.getRepos(name)
    // }, [])



    console.log('asd',match);
    return(
        <div>
            <h1>Profile page</h1>
        </div>
    )
}
```

```js
import React, {useReducer} from "react"
import axios from 'axios'
import { CLEAR_USERS, GET_REPOS, GET_USER, SEARCH_USERS, SET_LOADING } from "../types"
import { GithubContext } from "./githubContex"
import { githubReducer } from "./githubReducer"

const CLIENT_ID = process.env.REACT_APP_CLIENT_ID
const CLIENT_SECRET = process.env.REACT_APP_CLIENT_SECRET

const withCreads = url => {
    return `${url}client_id=${CLIENT_ID}&client_secret=${CLIENT_SECRET}`
}

export const GithubState = ({children}) => {
    const initialState = {
        user: {},
        users: [],
        loading: false,
        repos: []
    }
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(githubReducer, initialState)

    const search = async value => {
        setLoading()

        const response = await axios.get(
           withCreads(`https://api.github.com/search/users?q=${value}&`)
        )

        dispatch({
            type: SEARCH_USERS,
            payload: response.data.items
        })
    }

    const getUser = async name => {
        setLoading()

        const response = await axios.get(
            withCreads(`https://api.github.com/users/users/${name}?`)
        )

        dispatch({
            type: GET_USER,
            payload: response.data
        })
    }

    const getRepos = async name => {
        setLoading()

        const response = await axios.get(
            withCreads(`https://api.github.com/users/users/${name}/repos?per_page=5&`)
        )

        dispatch({
            type: GET_REPOS,
            payload: response.data
        })
    }

    const clearUsers = () => dispatch({type: CLEAR_USERS})
    
    const setLoading = () => dispatch({type: SET_LOADING})

    const {user, users, repos, loading} = state

    return (
        <GithubContext.Provider value={{
            setLoading, search, getUser, getRepos, clearUsers,
            user, users, repos, loading
        }}>
            {children}
        </GithubContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

link to Github https://github.com/Eater228/React-Hooks

Comment: Have no idea what `mutch` is. The error should tell you where it is coming from, file and line. Also this path looks strange `"./context/github/GithunState"` Is it correct with the "n" instead of "b" for Github?

Comment: Sorry I wrote this question using google translate mutch = match. And the right way just when creating a component missed the key

Comment: Please update the question with the correct translation. I also wondered what mutch was, and was kind of annoyed when seeing you already knew that this was wrong an hour ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your `package.json` file and if you are using an older version of `react-router-dom` please use the latest version.

`match` prop should be passed down from the `Route` component and it will reflect the correct data as you are using `react-router-dom`.

**Update**

You are using `element` prop for rendering component and that's not the correct one. You should replace that `element` with `component` and it will work.

**Update**

Please consider using `useParams` hook instead of that `match` prop.
https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview#reading-url-parameters

Comment: Version react-router-dom 6.2.1 updated but it didn't help again shows that match undefinde

Comment: @ЮраОлексыйко please check above update.

Comment: If I use component I get an error (Matched leaf route at location "/" does not have an element. This means it will render an <Outlet /> with a null value by default resulting in an "empty" page.) I need to use an element from version 6

Comment: @ЮраОлексыйко the original approach is deprecated since v5.1 so you might consider using `useParams` hook in v6.